# Carousel Using Bulma CSS Framework

Tags: css, html, carousel, bulma

I am new to Bulma Framework. I have started with following in my HTML file. I have not installed any package.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/js/all.js"></script>

 <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        Hello World
      </h1>
      <p class="subtitle">
        My first website with <strong>Bulma</strong>!
      </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

What is the best way to use bulma?

Also I have to use Bulma carousel. How can I add bulma carousel css and js? Also is it possible to display dotted navigation like Owl carousel in Bulma carousel?

Comment: please refer the Bulma documentation

Comment: Already checked it but bot understanding. it's confusing.

Answer (score 2):

In order to integrate **Bulma-Carousel** to your project follow the steps below:
Link the [CSS](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css) file of **Bulma** and the [CSS](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-carousel@4.0.4/dist/css/bulma-carousel.min.css) and [JS](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-carousel@4.0.4/dist/js/bulma-carousel.min.js) files of Bulma-Carousel.
Then, initialize **Bulma-Carousel** in a seperate `.js` file.

Here's a starter project to help you get started:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-carousel@4.0.4/dist/css/bulma-carousel.min.css" />
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-carousel@4.0.4/dist/js/bulma-carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="scripts.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="section">
      <div class="container is-clipped">
        <div id="slider">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
              <figure class="image is-16by9 is-covered">
                <img
                  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550921082-c282cdc432d6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80"
                  alt=""
                />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="item__title">
                Mon titre 1
              </div>
              <div class="item__description">
                Ici une petite description pour tester le slider
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
              <figure class="image is-16by9 is-covered">
                <img
                  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550945771-515f118cef86?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80"
                  alt=""
                />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="item__title">
                Mon titre 2
              </div>
              <div class="item__description">
                Ici une petite description pour tester le slider
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
              <figure class="image is-16by9 is-covered">
                <img
                  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550971264-3f7e4a7bb349?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80"
                  alt=""
                />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="item__title">
                Mon titre 3
              </div>
              <div class="item__description">
                Ici une petite description pour tester le slider
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
              <figure class="image is-16by9 is-covered">
                <img
                  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550931937-2dfd45a40da0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80"
                  alt=""
                />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="item__title">
                Mon titre 4
              </div>
              <div class="item__description">
                Ici une petite description pour tester le slider
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
              <figure class="image is-16by9 is-covered">
                <img
                  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550930516-af8b8cc4f871?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80"
                  alt=""
                />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="item__title">
                Mon titre 5
              </div>
              <div class="item__description">
                Ici une petite description pour tester le slider
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
              <figure class="image video-container is-16by9">
                <iframe type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H0v773vKS_U" frameborder="0"></iframe>
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="item__title">
                Mon titre 6
              </div>
              <div class="item__description">
                Ici une petite description pour tester le slider
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

**scripts.js**

```
bulmaCarousel.attach('#slider', {
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  infinite: true,
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure that jQuary is actually needed. It works fine for me without it.

Comment: @aldi can you change the data-size based on screen in bulma carousal extension?  
<div class="carousel carousel-animated carousel-animate-slide" data-size="3"> </div

Comment: @Ryder Yes, you can use `data-size` attribute.

Comment: @aldi thanks for the reply. Yes, I know I can use the data-size, my actual question was,  can we change the data-size based on screen size dynamically? such as for desktop data-size=4 and for full-hd data-size=6. I know I can use javascript to do that but is there anything inbuilt in Bulma? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Ryder It's not possible through HTML, so your best bet is to implement this type of function through JavaScript.

Comment: @aldi I have this kind of working on an example page, but the slider appears with a width  equaling all of the embedded photos.  Is there a way to limit to just my usual page width?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the implementation of a Carousel with Bulma in here:

https://wikiki.github.io/components/carousel/

It's built on the Bulma Framework so it integrates easily with it.

You would need this basic structure

```
<div class='carousel carousel-animated carousel-animate-slide'>
 <div class='carousel-container'>
    <div class='carousel-item has-background is-active'>
      <img class="is-background" src="" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
      <div class="title">Merry Christmas</div>
    </div>
    <div class='carousel-item has-background'>
      <img class="is-background" src="https://wikiki.github.io/images/singer.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
      <div class="title">Original Gift: Offer a song with <a href="https://lasongbox.com" target="_blank">La Song Box</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class='carousel-item has-background'>
      <img class="is-background" src="https://wikiki.github.io/images/sushi.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
      <div class="title">Sushi time</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

You'll also need to import it with this once you download the package.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/bulma-extensions/bulma-carousel/dist/bulma-carousel.min.js"></script>
```

And initialize it with this line in you JavaScript file

```
var carousels = bulmaCarousel.attach();
```

Comment: I have added all these and still my carousel not working, can you please me on this, I have a question on that aswell : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091200/bulma-carousel-not-responding