# Bulma Carousel not responding

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bulma

I am trying to incorporate the bulma carousel to my react application but it seems that its not going to work.
I have tried implementing it using [Bulma Carousel](https://wikiki.github.io/components/carousel/) this documentation as well but still it doesn't seems to work.

Here is my code, Feel free to point out where to do things correct to work it.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" />
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
  <title>Simple React App</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/bulma-extensions/bulma-carousel/dist/js/bulma-carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      var carousels = bulmaCarousel.attach();
      console.log(carousels);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Here is my Carousel Component:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const Carousel = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="carousel carousel-animated carousel-animate-slide">
        <div className="carousel-container">
          <div className="carousel-item has-background is-active">
            <img
              className="is-background"
              src="https://wikiki.github.io/images/merry-christmas.jpg"
              alt=""
              width="640"
              height="310"
            />
            <div className="title">Merry Christmas</div>
          </div>
          <div className="carousel-item has-background">
            <img
              className="is-background"
              src="https://wikiki.github.io/images/singer.jpg"
              alt=""
              width="640"
              height="310"
            />
            <div className="title">
              Original Gift: Offer a song with{" "}
              <a href="https://lasongbox.com" target="_blank">
                La Song Box
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="carousel-item has-background">
            <img
              className="is-background"
              src="https://wikiki.github.io/images/sushi.jpg"
              alt=""
              width="640"
              height="310"
            />
            <div className="title">Sushi time</div>
          </div>
          <div className="carousel-item has-background">
            <img
              className="is-background"
              src="https://wikiki.github.io/images/life.jpg"
              alt=""
              width="640"
              height="310"
            />
            <div className="title">Life</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="carousel-navigation is-overlay">
          <div className="carousel-nav-left">
            <i className="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true" />
          </div>
          <div className="carousel-nav-right">
            <i className="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

I have also install the Bulma extension in my node modules using `npm i bulma-extensions`

*Note : I am new to React and Bulma*

Comment: Do you get any errors on console?

Comment: No just a vertical set of images display, the carousel doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 0):

So i finally found an interesting way to make it run.

It seems that the carousel doesn't seems to work with the js included in the npm version `npm i bulma-extensions`.

When ever i tried to add the js file from modules from one of mentioned method on [carousel extension](https://wikiki.github.io/components/carousel/) and it doesn't seems to work

However, When i used this tag from CDN it works fine

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-carousel@3.0.0/dist/js/bulma-carousel.min.js"></script>
```